# Query prints posts without specific categories

Tags: posts, wp-query, categories

How to query post without specific categories for example "two"and "three"

```
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'showposts' => 3);

        $category_home = new WP_Query($args);

        if($wp_query->have_posts()) :
        while($wp_query->have_posts()) :
        $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: have you checked https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#category-parameters ? you might need to use the category ids for this.

Comment: Are you trying to print the posts without including the category in the displayed HTML? Or trying to query posts without using categories?

Comment: @Pixelsmith trying to quert post without using categories

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this array:

```
        <?php
        $args = array(
          'post_type' => 'post',
            'orderby' => 'date',
              'order' => 'DESC',
          'showposts' => '3',
          'cat' => '-1,-2,-3',


        );
```